# Pydev using wrong IPython version?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, ipython

I have Pydev 2.7, Python 3.2 and IPython 0.13 installed.
However, when I run the interactive console in Eclipse it says

```
PyDev console: using IPython 0.11
```

I cannot imagine where IPython 0.11 is supposed to come from. How can I check?

After running the console,  `import IPython; IPython.__version__` also gives me the correct version 0.13.

Is it IPython 0.13 in the console now or is something wrong?

Comment: I think it was hard coded in PyDev as IPython version 0.11 was the current version when IPython integration was added.

Comment: To explain a bit more: IPython changed a lot between 0.10 and 0.11, so PyDev probably needed different code to integrate the new version. So that message might mean '0.11 or above'.

Comment: OK, apparently there are even class names containing "ipython" and "11". Can I check the version in the running IPython instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're fine. I tried

```
IPython.__version__
```

and also get 0.13  in the PyDev console:

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
C:\Python27\python.exe 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
PyDev console: using IPython 0.11
import IPython
IPython.__version__
Out[1]: '0.13.1'
```